# Get definition for columns stored in another table without joining twice

Tags: t-sql, join, query-optimization

Given two tables where two columns in the first table, with potentially distinct values, reference a single column in the second, is there a way to "define" these columns without joining the tables twice?

For example, if Table one is

```
TransactionRecord( UserCreated char(3), UserModified char(3), ... , OtherData )
```

And table two is

```
Users( UserID char(3), UserName varchar(50), ... , OtherData )
```

Is there a way to get a result set that is

```
Result( TransactionData, UserNameCreated, UserNameModified )
```

without joining the first table to the second twice? So far I have been able to achieve this with the following SQL.

```sql
SELECT OtherData, uc.[UserName], uf.UserName 
FROM TransactionData
    LEFT JOIN Users uc ON TransactionData.UserCreated = uc.UserID
    LEFT JOIN Users um ON TransactionData.UserModified= um.UserID
```

But these tables contain a rather large number of records, and since joins are relatively expensive I am looking for a better way. I'm using TSQL and the database server is SQL Server 2005.

Comment: to avoid this "double" join you can store the user names in two separate columns. I think an index will solve your performance issue

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean about storing the username in two separate columns.

Comment: TransactionData has another two columns: UserCreatedName, UserModifiedName

Comment: Okay. I understand what you mean. In this case I'm not sure that introducing two new fields to the table would be justified. This is also the database of a vendor-provided software, so I think that modifying the table and populating the column would probably have to be done with something like a trigger, vs. in the application code where it probably should be.

Comment: I don't like this me either. I would use this in a very extreme case. However, a good index is your best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way round this, I think correct indexing is the only way to go (and should be fine unless you have tens of millions of rows).

For instance, you need a table where the user id is a clustered unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserID] ON [dbo].[table]
(
[UserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

A clustered unique index will work fine here and will certainly be less expensive than additional columns or any other technique I can think off.

(A non clustered index would do in a crunch, but clustered would be better (as the user id's would be stored sequentially and read much faster - I say this incase your users table already has a clustered index on a different column (you can only have one clustered index per table).

Answer (score 0):

User in two columns is basically not 3rd normal form.   I would join on UserID and have a bit column for action (0 = add, 1 = revise).